# How to calculate the time needed to intersect points moving in random directions with constant speed from a given start position?

Tags: java, algorithm

A more detailed description of the problem I need help with is as follows: I am given a set of N points. Each point has 4 values (*x,y,v and a*) describing its *x* and *y* start coordinates(-10^6 <=*x*, *y*<=10^6), speed (1<=*v*<100) and direction (0<*a*<2pi). My point on the other hand, is defined by the starting point coordinates (the origin) and the speed which is always greater than those of any N point. The task of "my point" is to intercept all N points upon which every N point changes its direction and starts going back to the origin with the same constant speed as initially. Finally, my task as a programmer is to find a way to calculate the time before every N point is at origin.

Unfortunately, I am completely baffled by this problem and don't know where to start. Tried googling it but didn't find any conclusive answers. And so as I even don't know where to start, I would greatly appreciate if someone could give me a hint on how to approach this problem. This was an interview question and while I didn't get the job I could still learn something.

Thank you for your time and please forgive any formatting mistakes  or badly structured post formulation. I am trying my best.

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: You need to read [ask], then edit your question to meet those guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I tried to edit my question to the best of my ability. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71331/calculating-how-to-intercept-a-moving-object maybe this can help you